# What's a fast query to delete duplicate primary keys instead of updating them (keeping the latest record)?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, primary-key, insert-update

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration to churn large JSON data into a MySQL database.

Anyway, of course there is the option of pure table insert, but also a table insert/ update (it will lookup a key to update, and if not found, insert the row).

This data is basically the current representation/ state of tickets -- so I need all data columns for a given row updated based on the unique Ticket ID.

With Pentaho, and likely most applications, updating is far slower than inserting. Especially since, at least with this application, you can have up to 25 connections writing (inserting) data at the same time, but only (1) process doing the lookup-then-write.

Therefore I'd rather do the following: Insert all the data (once a day or so) .. and then immediately after, run a query that deletes all duplicate Ticket IDs -- EXCEPT for the one with the greatest (aka latest) "update time."

I feel like that would be much faster -- and am wondering how to accomplish this in MySQL. I think it's something like

Delete from [table-name] where ticket_id = ticket_id and update_time < update_time, but I'm not certain if this is correct or variables are needed to compare data in an inter-row fashion.

Comment: In MySQL you can't have duplicate primary keys anyway. So if an insert is with an existing primary key, MySQL will reject automatically.

Comment: Ah, I may have mispoken. I'm just using Ticket ID as a unique identifier. I don't think I actually set it up as a primary key.

Comment: A unique identifier won't allow duplicates, either. What do you *really* have? (Paste CREATE TABLE statement into your question.)

Comment: Okay it's not a unique identifier, it's just that the table reflects the current state of each ticket. There SHOULD be one row for each Ticket_Id. I haven't formally or technically done anything special to the Ticket_ID field --- it just, semantically speaking, SHOULD be unique. In practice, it won't be, temporarily, because I feel using 25 connections to write data, and deleting old duplicates later, is faster than updating a unique key. I'm just trying to figure out how to accomplish that.

Comment: Can't you do like make the TICKETID Unique field or as primary field, so that MySQL rejects the duplicate rows while inserting itself.? Have you tried that.?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I found this method on another page:

```
DELETE FROM ztable zt
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM ztable ex
WHERE ex.CaseKey = zt.CaseKey
AND ex.recordDate > zt.recordDate
);
```